# Can't connect to the Pi after cloning the SD card

Tags: raspbian, opencv, filesystem

I want to make a new SD card with Raspbian and OpenCV installed. Instead of making it from scratch, I have already done this from another SD card that I use with raspberry.

After cloning the SD card, I can't connect to the cloned SD card with Raspberry, and the filesystem is so different from the SD card that I cloned.

I have used the `dd` command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=raspbian.img
```

In the new SD card

```
df -h
umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
sudo dd bs=4M if=raspbian.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

I get the following error when connecting the pi 2 with a HDMI cable to a laptop :
**end kernel panic - not syncing : VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179.2)**
Is there any method to clone SD cards with possibility to use and connect both after the cloning operation?

Note :
the two sd cards have the same size : 32 GB . But they are from different types (manufacturers), the cloned one is a samsung class 10 32 gb --> cloned to kingston 32 gb class 4

Links :

- [Backups](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/filesystem/backup.md)
- [Installing Operating System images on Linux](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md)

Comment: Which utility did you use for cloning ?

Comment: What you're doing looks good. It should work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make use of GUI utilities such as `win32 disk imager` on windows platform or `image-writer` on ubuntu. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes , i have tested win32 fro writing to cards it's super easy to do i think i will try it and let you know ;)

Comment: I have had the same experience and it was the result of a corrupted copy of the image. Some cards seem to work better than others. In my case, a nice Samsung class 10 card wouldn't work reliably, but an old Sandisk class 4 card worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the exact sizes of both of the cards (eg. using `fdisk`)?
If the target card is a little bit smaller than the the original card, duplicating using `dd` can (or even will?) fail.

I roughly documented a way that finally worked for me [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36269/34584).

Comment: yes the two sd card are the same size : 32 GB , but they are from different types , the cloned one is a samsung class 10 32 gb cloned to kingston 32 gb class 4

Comment: I don't think the brands or classes are important and make a difference, but size does. Use `sudo fdisk -l` in Terminal to figure out the exact sizes on Byte level and not Gigabyte level! The Gigabyte value is just a rough estimate.

Comment: the kingston card 32 gb : 31197233152 bytes ... and the samsung class 10 32gb  : 31 922 344 428 bytes.  so they are a little bit different in size ... is This can be the cause of the  problem ??

Comment: @Frankenstein Yes! This is exactly what I'm talking about. The target card seems to be slightly smaller compared to the source card.

Comment: so i can do nothing now ... the card is corrupted !!! is there any alternatives ?

Comment: Yes, just follow the link in my answer.

Comment: okk I will try it and i let you know

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you had a block error in an inconsequential part of your SD card.  This would cause dd to quit writing the current block and resume immediately with the next block, so your file system would be off.

Including "sync" in both your dd commands may fix it by zeroing the remaining bytes in the bad block, but you would possibly also need to reduce your block size so that the zeroed portion doesn't take bytes out of other important blocks.

Comment: thanks ... can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: `sudo dd bs=4M sync if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=raspbian.img`  It's honestly just as easy as adding the word sync.  Like I said, maybe consider dropping block size from 4M to maybe 4096 (no letter, I mean 4096 bytes).  This will be slower, but will be more reliable.  You could also pipe it, which makes it read and right simultaneously, instead of read block, write block, repeat:  `sudo dd bs=4M sync if=/dev/mmcblk0 | dd bs=4M sync of=raspbian.img`.