# kernel panic not syncing: VFS unknown-block 179,6 after cloning SD

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, kernel

I have set up my Raspbian and need to clone the SD Card to about 20 other Raspberry Pis now.

I used the following command (on OS X) to clone the SD Card:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=~/Desktop/pi.img bs=1m
gzip -c ~/Desktop/pi.img > ~/Desktop/pi_img.gz

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3
gzip -dc ~/Desktop/pi_img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m
```

I also tried the same thing with disk (instead of rdisk) and without gzipping it.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk3 of=~/Desktop/pi.dmg
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3
sudo newfs_msdos -F 16 /dev/disk3
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/pi.dmg of=/dev/disk3
```

results are the same:

**kernel panic not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block 179,6**

Of cause the main SD Card still works. This error is only on the cloned SD Card

Is there another way to clone the SD Card 1:1? or is there a way to fix the broken cloned SD?
If possible this should be an automatable solution because I have to do this to 20+ PIs 2-3 times a year or so.

**EDIT
I just noticed, that my .dmg image has 4 partitions (boot, RECOVERY, disk4s3, disk4s6) but the cloned SD Card has only 3 (boot, RECOVERY, disk4s6).
So.. disk4s3 seems to be the problem..**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the exact sizes of both of the cards (eg. using `fdisk`)?
If the target card is a little bit smaller than the the original card, duplicating using `dd` can (or even will?) fail.

The same error happened to me and I solved it the following way on Ubuntu running on my Mac (following this [tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/) creating an Ubuntu live USB stick using [Mac Linux USB Loader](http://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/)). You need to do this under Linux to be able to access the Linux file system on the SD cards:

1. I manually replicated the partition table to the new card using `fdisk`.
2. Formatted the partitions using `mkfs`.
3. Copying the files using `rsync -av`.

The card was perfectly booting afterwards.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the method you used, I am kinda stuck here even after trying out several options with the `dd` command

Comment: As suggested, if the target card is smaller than the source card, don't use `dd`. Follow the above instructions instead using `rsync`.

Comment: That is exactly the problem I faced after trying to clone an SD card on a Mac.  Doing it on Linux resolved the issue.

Comment: More recently, Pishrink is a viable option.